# ImportError: No module named arff

Tags: python, import, machine-learning, arff

Here's a simple code as in this [link](https://code.google.com/p/arff/) to read an arff file in python (the commented one didn't work too):

```
import arff
for row in arff.load('heart_train.arff'):
        print(row.sex)
```

And here's the error I receive:

```
python id3.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "id3.py", line 1, in <module>
    import arff
ImportError: No module named arff
```

"heart_train" arff file data is like:

```
@relation cleveland-14-heart-disease
@attribute 'age' real
@attribute 'sex' { female, male}
@attribute 'cp' { typ_angina, asympt, non_anginal, atyp_angina}
@attribute 'trestbps' real
@attribute 'chol' real
@attribute 'fbs' { t, f}
@attribute 'restecg' { left_vent_hyper, normal, st_t_wave_abnormality}
@attribute 'thalach' real
@attribute 'exang' { no, yes}
@attribute 'oldpeak' real
@attribute 'slope' { up, flat, down}
@attribute 'ca' real
@attribute 'thal' { fixed_defect, normal, reversable_defect}
@attribute 'class' { negative, positive}
@data
63,male,typ_angina,145,233,t,left_vent_hyper,150,no,2.3,down,0,fixed_defect,negative
37,male,non_anginal,130,250,f,normal,187,no,3.5,down,0,normal,negative
41,female,atyp_angina,130,204,f,left_vent_hyper,172,no,1.4,up,0,normal,negative
56,male,atyp_angina,120,236,f,normal,178,no,0.8,up,0,normal,negative
57,female,asympt,120,354,f,normal,163,yes,0.6,up,0,normal,negative
57,male,asympt,140,192,f,normal,148,no,0.4,flat,0,fixed_defect,negative
...
```

Comment: did you have this line in your code: `import arff` ?

Comment: yeah, I had. It just didn't get copied.

Comment: Actually it is in the question but doesn't show!!!?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should rename your script from `arff.py` to something different, `arfftest.py` for example. Python cant import `arff` module you need because name of it is the same as your app file name.

And if you havent installed `arff` package itself, install it with pip or easy_install:

```
pip install arff
# or easy_install arff
# or pypm install arff
```

Comment: `Monas-MacBook-Pro: mona$ python id3.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "id3.py", line 1, in <module>
    import arff
ImportError: No module named arff`

Comment: @MonaJalal that error means that python cant find arff. Did you installed it?

Comment: Thanks I installed it using `pypm install arff` I am receiving this error: ` python id3.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "id3.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(row.sex)  
  File "/Users/mona/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/arff/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattr__(self, key)
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'`

Comment: which python version you ve ? its Tested on python 2.7 and 3.2

Answer (score 2):

**After I change your, arff file it works:**

**NB: I removed the single code from the second column of the attribute.**

**Here is the arff file:**

```
@relation cleveland-14-heart-disease
@attribute age real
@attribute sex { female, male}
@attribute cp { typ_angina, asympt, non_anginal, atyp_angina}
@attribute trestbps real
@attribute chol real
@attribute fbs { t, f}
@attribute restecg { left_vent_hyper, normal, st_t_wave_abnormality}
@attribute thalach real
@attribute exang { no, yes}
@attribute oldpeak real
@attribute slope { up, flat, down}
@attribute ca real
@attribute thal { fixed_defect, normal, reversable_defect}
@attribute class { negative, positive}
@data
63,male,typ_angina,145,233,t,left_vent_hyper,150,no,2.3,down,0,fixed_defect,negative
37,male,non_anginal,130,250,f,normal,187,no,3.5,down,0,normal,negative
41,female,atyp_angina,130,204,f,left_vent_hyper,172,no,1.4,up,0,normal,negative
56,male,atyp_angina,120,236,f,normal,178,no,0.8,up,0,normal,negative
57,female,asympt,120,354,f,normal,163,yes,0.6,up,0,normal,negative
57,male,asympt,140,192,f,normal,148,no,0.4,flat,0,fixed_defect,negative
```

Snippet and output:

```
:/tmp:~ cat a.py
import arff
for row in arff.load('heart_train.arff'):
   print(row.sex)
:/tmp:~ python a.py
male
male
female
male
female
male
:/tmp:~
male
:/tmp:~
```